# Change the headerToolbar month week icons in FullCalendar Vue3 without Bootstrap

Tags: vuejs3, fullcalendar, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify3 for the whole site. I found in the FullCalendar docs that we can only use Bootstrap to change the headerToolbar icons.

I'm wondering if we have any other way to change the month week icons in FullCalendar Vue3 Typescript without Bootstrap.

I cannot use Bootstrap which will affect my site design.

Comment: It's not in the documentation,  so no, there isn't